# How do I see my FPS counter in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've been trying to see my laptop performance in Minecraft Bedrock but I've been unable to do it. I try to see my FPS using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Xbox Game Bar) but the FPS display counter does not work. It says to restart the computer but it doesn't work. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a legit way to view your frame rate in bedrock edition. However if you have a Nvidia graphics card, you should be able to use Geforce Experience to view your fps ingame.